# How to access datasource information in spring boot with spring data jpa and hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to perform an health check on my application that uses spring boot with spring data jpa and hibernate.
I need to do this with jpa and not make specific to any implementation.
In EclipseLink we can use EntityManagerFactoryDelegate as shown below, but I dont know How to do this with spring data jpa and hibernate.

```
EntityManagerFactoryDelegate  delegate = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.class);

PersistenceInfo = delegate.getSetupImpl().getPersistenceUnitInfo();
DataSourceImpl dataSource = (DataSource) info.getNpnJtaDataSource();
return dataSource.getName();
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this in spring data jpa using hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring boot `actuator` dependency for healthcheck doesn't need to configure externally. Once you define Datasource Bean it will auto pick database healthcheck.

if you want to enable/disable database health check you can use the below property,

```
management.health.db.enabled=<boolean, true || false>
```

implementation reference :https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html